# Drop Down List Selected Item

Tags: c#, sql, html-select

I am trying to select a dynamic data from drop down list and view the details of selected items. I have no problem in populating the drop down list with data from database. However, when I selected some items, it does not shows up the detail.

In my presentation layer, when drop down list item is selected:

```
protected void ddlScheduleList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string address = ddlScheduleList.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Distribution scheduledIndv = new Distribution();

        scheduledIndv = packBLL.getDistributionDetail(address);

        if (scheduledIndv == null)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Null");
        }
        else
        {
            tbScheduleDate.Text = scheduledIndv.packingDate.ToString();
            tbBeneficiary.Text = scheduledIndv.beneficiary;
        }

    }
```

In my business logic layer, I get the selected address and pass it to data access layer:

```
public Distribution getDistributionDetail(string address)
    {
        Distribution scheduledIndv = new Distribution();

        return scheduledIndv.getDistributionDetail(address);
    }
```

In my data access layer, I tested out the SQL statement already. It gives me what I wanted. But it just won't show up in web page.

```
public Distribution getDistributionDetail(string address)
    {
        Distribution distributionFound = null;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FoodBankDB.GetConnectionString())) // get your connection string from the other class here
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT d.packingDate, b.name FROM dbo.Distributions d " +
            " INNER JOIN dbo.Beneficiaries b ON d.beneficiary = b.id " +
            " WHERE b.addressLineOne = '" + address + "'", connection);
            connection.Open();

            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    DateTime packingDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["packingDate"].ToString());
                    string beneficiary = dr["beneficiary"].ToString();

                    distributionFound = new Distribution(packingDate, beneficiary);
                }
            }
        }
        return distributionFound;
    }
```

And my execute Reader method in another separated class:

```
 public static string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString;

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return connectionString;
    }

public static SqlDataReader executeReader(string query)
    {
        SqlDataReader result = null;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FoodBankDB executeReader: " + query);

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        result = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

I wonder what went wrong. Is it about the (!IsPostBack) or?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you will need to let it post back in order to populate it. Or databind it to the database.

Comment: I found out my mistake already. I forgot to enable post back on the drop down list. Thank you

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You found your mistake, but to avoid Sql Injection, modify your code like this:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT d.packingDate, b.name FROM dbo.Distributions d " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.Beneficiaries b ON d.beneficiary = b.id " +
                " WHERE b.addressLineOne = @address", connection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
```

Comment: what's the negative impact of Sql injection?

Comment: With sql injection an attacker can access all of your data stored in SQL database. And if the SQL server is not configured properly, it's possible to perform arbitrary code execution.